# IntValue always is equal to 0 even though it isn't

Tags: lua, roblox

So I'm having a problem where I'm trying to get the value of an IntValue but it always gives me 0, even if the value is not 0. There is no error that appears and it is inside a server script. I can't tell what the problem is:

```
local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

local Clicks = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
Clicks.Name = "Clicks"

local Multiplier = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
Multiplier.Name = "Multiplier"

-- a bunch of datastore stuff


game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(plr)
print("removing")
local approved, errortext = pcall(function()
    print(plr.leaderstats.Clicks.Value, plr.leaderstats.Multiplier.Value)
    datastore:SetAsync(plr.UserId.."-save", {plr.leaderstats.Clicks.Value, plr.leaderstats.Multiplier.Value})
    
end)

if approved then
    
    print("data saved")
    print( plr.leaderstats.Multiplier.Value, plr.leaderstats.Clicks.Value)
else
    
    print("idiot data wont save")
    
end

end)
```

And it just prints 0 for the multiplier value every single time.

This is the code that changes the multiplier value:

```
local leaderstats = game.Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
local clicks = leaderstats.Clicks
local folder = script.Parent.multipliers
local multiplier = leaderstats.Multiplier

for i,v in pairs(folder:GetChildren()) do

local cost = v.Cost

v.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    
    print(v)
    
    if multiplier.Value > tonumber(v.Name) then
        
        print("already bbogt")
        
    end
    
    if multiplier.Value + 1 == tonumber(v.Name) then
        
        if cost.Value > clicks.Value then
            
            print("not enough moneys smh my head")
            
        elseif cost.Value <= clicks.Value then
            
            print("rich smh mynhead")
            
            clicks.Value -= cost.Value
            
            multiplier.Value = multiplier.Value + 1
        end
        
        
    elseif multiplier.Value == 0 and v.Name == "2" then
        if 5 > clicks.Value then

            print("not enough moneys smh my head")

        elseif 5 <= clicks.Value then

            print("rich smh mynhead")

            clicks.Value -= 5

            multiplier.Value = 2
            print(clicks.Value)
        end
        
    end
    
end)

end
```

Comment: where do you assign a value to that value that prints 0? I only see you connect some event handler.

Comment: oops sorry i'll add that script

Answer (score 0):

How are you changing the Value of the Multiplier? When You change the value of the Multiplier from a script, check manually from the explorer if the value is not 0. For example in this code, it does change the variable's value but not the actual Intvalue's value.

```lua
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Intvalue = Player.leaderstats.IntValue.value

IntValue = IntValue + 10
```

Basically what happens here is that the game gets the value of IntValue and returns that as the variable. Then when you change the value of the variable, it does increase the value of the variable, but it does not change the actual value of the intvalue in the Explorer. So it would be better to do it this way:

```lua
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local IntValue = Players.leaderstats.IntValue

IntValue.value = IntValue.value + 10
```

Basically this changes the value of the actual Intvalue in the explorer instead of the other example where it just changes the variable. So If you would print the Variable "IntValue" in the first example, it would still print 10 like the second example, but that would print the variable's value and not the actual one.

What I thought was that you might be changing the value of it the wrong way so that it doesn't actually change it, and so it says "0" in the output. But if the value is in-fact not 0 in the explorer, then I don't really know if I can help much.

Also I am not that good of an explainer, So if I did not explain my point well, Then basically just check the Value of the Multiplier manually in the explorer. And make sure that you are changing the actual value of the Multiplier, and not just the variable inside of an script somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the code, is the value variable constantly updating or is the value set? If the value was set as a variable once before the other lines, it must mean the code hasn't updated the value leaving it as 0. If these two code batches are looped then I am not quite sure but just double check if the code is recursively looping so the value can update. You could simply add a while loop including a wait() so the code runs recursively.

(These variables below must be updated maybe with a while loop)

```
local clicks = leaderstats.Clicks
local folder = script.Parent.multipliers
local multiplier = leaderstats.Multiplier
```

or if you want the variables at front, then the whole script must be nested in a while loop, like this...

```
while true do
wait()
local leaderstats = game.Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("leaderstats")
local clicks = leaderstats.Clicks
local folder = script.Parent.multipliers
local multiplier = leaderstats.Multiplier

for i,v in pairs(folder:GetChildren()) do

local cost = v.Cost

v.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    
    print(v)
    
    if multiplier.Value > tonumber(v.Name) then
        
        print("already bbogt")
        
    end
    
    if multiplier.Value + 1 == tonumber(v.Name) then
        
        if cost.Value > clicks.Value then
            
            print("not enough moneys smh my head")
            
        elseif cost.Value <= clicks.Value then
            
            print("rich smh mynhead")
            
            clicks.Value -= cost.Value
            
            multiplier.Value = multiplier.Value + 1
        end
        
        
    elseif multiplier.Value == 0 and v.Name == "2" then
        if 5 > clicks.Value then

            print("not enough moneys smh my head")

        elseif 5 <= clicks.Value then

            print("rich smh mynhead")

            clicks.Value -= 5

            multiplier.Value = 2
            print(clicks.Value)
        end
        
    end
    
end)
end
end
```

If this didn't satisfy you, try do some more research on the issue.